# aspx page with entity datasource in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

We are hosting some aspx pages in classic asp application.  These aspx pages use manual code for building datasource.  Is there a way to use ObjectDataSource for this?

Trying it gives error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The element 'buildProviders' cannot be defined below the application level.
```

Note that asp classic site is hosted as virtual directory under IIS.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to mix that fail thing called asp with a .net application? Still can't understand why Microsoft decided to call it asp.net, because it only confuses people.

Comment: I am sure that it's a bad idea to do that.  But it's already mixed up.  Later it will be all converted to NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message because you do not have setup your directory as net application.

You must understand that asp and asp.net are two different thinks.

Can work together if you setup both, if you setup only the one, the other is not work, so to run asp.net you need to assign it as web app, give a pool, and have all the needed files and directory to start.